# splitting a large tab delimited file in python

Tags: python, split, large-files, csv

I have a large tab delimited file containing about 1.4 million lines and 50 columns. Before I do anything with the data contained in the file I want to split this large file into about a few thousand smaller files. The first column of my file contains position information, and I want each smaller file to be a specific interval based on this information. In separate lists I have the start and stop of each interval that I want to split the larger file by. Here is the part of my code that does this operation, the start and stop positions are contained in lists called start_L and stop_L:

```
for i in range(len(id)):
   out1=((file%s.txt)%(id[i]))
   table=open('largefile.tsv',"r")
   start=int(start_L[i])
   stop=int(stop_L[i])
   table.next()
   temp_out=open(out1,"w")
   reader=csv.reader(table,delimiter="\t")
   for line in reader:
       if int(line[0]) in range(start,stop):
           for y in line:
               temp_out.write(("%s\t")%(y))
           temp_out.write("\n")
    else:
        if int(line[0]) > stop:
            break
        else:
            pass
print "temporary file..." , id[i]
```

The above code achieves what I want, but is extremely slow. It can process the first hundred or so intervals in a matter of minutes, but gets exponentially slower with each passing interval, so it takes days to run. Is there a faster, or more efficient way of doing this? I believe the problem is that it has to scan over the entire file to find the positions within the specified interval each time through the loop.

Comment: is the CSV file ordered by position information (i.e. column 1) ?

Comment: by the way, you shouldn't use `id` as a variable, as this will override Python's built-in `id` function.

Comment: yes...it is ordered by position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried to keep this in the spirit of your code.  It only iterates thru the big file once, it does not bother to parse the lines via the csv module as you were just rejoining them during the write.

```
id=("a","b")
start_L=(1,15)
stop_L=(16,40)

i=0
table=open('largefile.tsv',"r")
out1=(("file%s.txt")%(id[i]))
temp_out=open(out1,"w")

# start iterating through the file 
for line in table:
     stop=int(stop_L[i])

     # Split the line into a position piece, and a 
     # throw away variable based upon the 1st tab char
     position,the_rest= line.split("\t",1)

     # I'm ignoring start as you mentioned it was sorted in the file
     if int(position) >= stop :
           # Close the current file
           temp_out.close()

           # Increment index so file name is pulled from id properly
           # If the index is past the length of the id list then 
           # break otherwise open the new file for writing
           i += 1  
           if (i < len(id)):
             out1=(("file%s.txt")%(id[i]))
             temp_out=open(out1,"w")
           else:
             break 

     temp_out.write(line)
```

My test file lines looked like

```
1       1a      b       c       d       e
2       2a      b       c       d       e
3       3a      b       c       d       e
```

This could be simplified quite a bit depending on your specific data but I hope it at least gives you a start.

Comment: IMHO, this could be a better, more complete answer if it at least indicated what it's doing and perhaps also why that's going to faster than the OP's approach (if it isn't obvious).

Comment: @martineau, I've added some comments to the code and moved the content of my first comment to the answer as well.  Let me know if you think something else would be useful.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the added comments to explain what each step is doing.

Comment: @abovezero, I just realized that as written it will skip the last line of the big file.  you'll have to tweak it a bit to pick that line up

Comment: @JamesThompson: Sorry, while you've definitely improved your answer, I'm reluctant to upvote something that is still so inefficient when you consider all the unnecessary work it's going to be doing 1.4 million times. Perhaps you should abandon a bit of the spirit of the OP's code and program more like a "Pythonista". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program slows down over time is because you are re-reading the CSV file over and over again for each output file. As the range you are looking moves down the CSV file, you need to read more and more data (most of which you skip) for every output file. Hence, the exponential decrease in performance.

You need to re-organise your code so that you read the CSV only once, sequentially, and pick out the ranges of interest (and writing them to a file) within the loop. This is only possible if the CSV is ordered by range (you said it is) and if your start_L/stop_L are also ordered correspondingly.

Comment: @abovezero: Also the `if int(line[0]) in range(start,stop):` is fairly inefficient and should be replaced with something faster like `if start <= int(line[0]) < stop:`.

Answer (score 1):

For most part the solution offered above helped me but since my input does not have the line #, I had to modify with the following changes.

```
    table=fileinput.input('largefile.csv',mode="r")
    #
    #
    #
         if fileinput.lineno() >= stop :
```

My file is | delimited with approx 600k lines and about 120MB in size; the entire file was split in just a few seconds.